# How to compute the determinant of a derivative ($det$ $df_x$)?

Tags: real-analysis, determinant

I have the following exercise:

$f : R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ is a $C^1$ function.

$Krit(f)$ is defined as:

$Krit(f):= \{x \in R^2$|$det$ $df_x = 0\}$.

and I want to show that $f(Krit(f))=0$

My question is, how do I compute $det$ $df_x$?

Comment: You probably want to show that the *measure* of $f(\mathrm{Krit}(f))$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

If $f=(g,h)$ and $x=(x_1,x_2), $

then $ df_x=\begin{pmatrix}g_{x_1}&g_{x_2}\\h_{x_1}&h_{x_2}\end{pmatrix}$,

hence

$ \det df_x=g_{x_1}h_{x_2}-g_{x_2}h_{x_1}$.